# C# thread starting order inconsistency

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm wondering why thread starting order is inconsistent with the executing order.

Here's my code.

```
class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));

        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Primary Thread";
        t1.Name = "Secondary Thread";

        t1.Start();
        Run();
    }
    void Run()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Thread#{Thread.CurrentThread.Name}: Begin");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Thread#{Thread.CurrentThread.Name}: End");
    }
}
```

`t1` thread starts earlier than `Main Thread` in code. Nevertheless, `Main Thread` executes first.
Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *t1 thread starts earlier than Main Thread in code* ... except `new Thread` is **called** from the main thread.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile...

Comment: Why do you think the order should be consistent?  What is forcing the operations to happen in a given order?

Comment: You call `t1.Start();` before you call `Run()`, so it's understandable that `t1` may call `Run` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to learn the fundamental rule of multithreaded coding before you write any more multithreaded code.

**In single-threaded code, you can assume that stuff stays the same unless something causes it to change.  In multi-threaded code, you must assume that stuff is changing unless something is keeping it the same.**

Your example is a specific case of that general rule. In this case the "stuff" that is changing is *the order in which side effects are observed*.  You have done almost nothing to keep that "stuff" still, and so it may change arbitrarily.

C# has very specific, clear rules documented in the C# specification regarding what side effects must be observed to be in a particular order in a multithreaded program; it is a *very short list*, and the side effects in your program are not on that list.

Two threads are permitted to run their side effects *in any order whatsoever with respect to each other*, but it's actually worse than that. In C# *multiple threads are not required to provide that a consistent ordering of side effects be observed from every thread*.

And indeed in your example you are observing that a particular order of calls to Debug.Write is chosen.  The running program can choose *any* order of interleaving those side effects; all that you are guaranteed is that you will not see a `Begin` on one thread *after* the `End` on the same thread.

Your question is:

> Why is this happening?

but as we have seen, this is the wrong question to ask.  The observed behaviour is *permitted* to happen, and it *does* happen, so asking *why* it happens doesn't help you.  **The question I think you intended to ask was**:

> How do I force two threads to run their side effects in a particular order with respect to each other?

But *this is not the right question either*.  The right question to ask is:

> How do I safely and effectively solve a particular performance problem using asynchrony?

The answer to that question depends on the actual problem, and creating a thread is often not the right solution. **Ideally you only create a thread when you have a CPU-bound task to solve, and an idle CPU that the thread can take over**.  Usually performance problems involving asynchrony are best solved on a single thread, with `await`.

Answer (score 1):

This result will make more sense if you phrase it in plain English:

```
My To-Do List:
    Instruct Bob to go off and do something
    Begin doing something yourself
```

... and the result you're getting is that Bob is starting his job before you start yours.  So?  There's no reason to think that Bob will be faster/slower than you in getting started.  Bob simply beat you to the punch.

It's the same thing with your code.  You told a separate task to start, and then kicked off a function.  Two bits of code are doing two separate things - there's not really any reason to suspect one should start faster than the other.